# SQL not returning correct values for a given user ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: one contains travel itinerary details such as the date created and the title (table name is `itineraries`) and the other user details (table name `users`). Users can add a travel agency to their itinerary.

I've put together the following statement **which works fine and as expected**, which is where I want to return all the itineraries for a given date range and travel agent id:

```
SELECT 
itineraries.travel_agent_id, 
itineraries.created_at as Date_Journey_Created, 
itineraries.title, 
itineraries.user_id as id

FROM `database`.`itineraries`

LEFT JOIN `database`.`users`
ON itineraries.id=users.id

WHERE itineraries.travel_agent_id='253' && (itineraries.created_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59')
```

In `itineraries`, the user ID field is named `user_id`, whereas in `users`, it's just `id`. No problem, I've worked out how to use an alias to change `user_id` to `id` before joining.

But what I want to do now is map the `id` field to the `full_name` field in the `users` table, so we get the user's full name alongside the numerical ID.

I've tried using `SELECT users.full_name` when selecting the rest of the tables and columns in the first part of the statement, like this:

```
SELECT
users.full_name,
itineraries.travel_agent_id, 
itineraries.created_at as Date_Journey_Created,
```

But it just returns data that is not correct for the given `id`, either a null value or just the wrong name completely. My DB data is correct because I can look at the `users` table manually myself and see what the `full_name` value is for a given `id`!

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong column to join:

```
SELECT 
   i.travel_agent_id, 
   i.created_at as Date_Journey_Created, 
   i.title, 
   i.user_id 
   u.full_name
FROM `database`.`itineraries` i
LEFT JOIN `database`.`users` u ON i.user_id = u.id
WHERE i.travel_agent_id='253' 
      AND i.created_at BETWEEN '2013-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'
```

By aliasing the column name in the SELECT, doesn't allow you to use that alias inside the where clause. 
You were probably joining with itinerary's id. Which wouldn't make much sense for you.
Also you have to use the word `AND` instead of `&&`

Comment: Thanks so much Felipe - you nailed it! You were right - it was the issue of having to use the original column name in the JOIN statement and **not** the aliased name. It now makes sense that my original SQL query pulled the itinerary IDs, not the user IDs that I wanted, due to the aforementioned reason. Many thanks again!